How energy density of EM wave oscillate?
In my textbook, the energy of a photon is given by

Energy = Planck's const * frequency

Since both Planck's const and frequency are constant for a given wave, the energy density should be constant but in my textbook

Energy density = $\epsilon_0 * (E_0 \sin(\omega t - k x))^2$

Since energy density is a function of $\sin^2$ it can become zero, which implies that the energy of the wave is zero.
How can that be possible? If so, where does all that energy go?
Can you explain these to a high school student?

Why -ve vote?  I am new to the platform I don't know how properly ask questions. Can you help me understand what I did wrong? that would be very helpful.

The question is fine so I answered it. I don't know why someone downvoted. Maybe they wanted you to do some more finding out on your own. But I think it is ok.

@Qmechanic thankyou for your guidance

A photon is a complete wave (a complete cycle) ... it can not be broken into pieces. The formula just describes where in the cycle the energy is greatest.  The whole cycle travels as a unit, yes in the middle it is zero ... but this means nothing.

There are two issues:

how to understand what classical electromagnetism says about em waves
how to understand the quantum physics (photons) and how it relates to (1).

In classical electromagnetism the energy per unit volume at any point in a field in otherwise empty space is
$$
u = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} B^2.
$$
An electromagnetic plane wave propagating in the $x$ direction has the form
$$
E = E_0 \sin(\omega t - kx)
$$
and
$$
B = E/c.
$$
For such a wave
$$
u = \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_0 E_0^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0 c^2}) \sin^2(\omega t - kx)
= \epsilon_0 E_0^2 \sin^2(\omega t - kx)
$$
so you have this correct. We can also find the total energy in some length $L$ and cross-section $A$. To do this one must integrate the energy density with respect to volume, which is the same as multiplying the position-averaged energy density by the volume. Taking $L$ to be an integer number of wavelengths, we get
$$
\mbox{Energy} = \frac{1}{2} A L \epsilon_0 E_0^2
$$
where the factor half comes from the average value of the $\sin^2$ function.
Note that it is ok for the energy density to have zeros at the nodes; that does not mean there is no energy. It means the energy has a distribution over space and time.
Now we can do a little quantum theory. An electromagnetic wave of large enough amplitude is described by a large number of photons, each having energy $h f$ (Planck's constant times frequency). If the amplitude is small, so that there is only a small number of photons, then the classical model does not work any more. But for a large wave it does. In that case the number of photons in a region of volume $AL$ will be
$$
N =  \frac{1}{2} \frac{A L \epsilon_0 E_0^2}{\hbar \omega}
$$
where I used $h f = \hbar \omega$. Note that a classical wave corresponds to a stream of many photons, not a single photon.

Sir can you explain the statment "energy has a distribution over space and time" I am unable to understand this statement

@muthunilavan .c The energy of the wave is moving through space and time; at any given moment, there are regions in the path of the wave that have 0 energy due to the wave.  A few moments later, those regions will once more have energy, as the wave moves into them; another region further along will have no energy.   You're assuming that the energy of the wave needs to exist at a point the entire time that the wave propagates through it.

What is EM radiation
You have radiation always and everywhere. It occurs primarily through the relaxation of subatomic particles by means of photon emission. The previously necessary excitation of the particles occurs through photon absorption. Photons are always and everywhere; in the background radiation as well as from every body that is warmer than 0° Kelvin (i.e. every body).
EM radiation can be broadband (a good example is blackbody radiation) or narrowband (lasers, cyclotron radiation, free electron lasers).
It can be unpolarized (blackbody, laser) or its magnetic and electric field components can be aligned (free electron laser, passage through polarizing filters).
In none of the cases described will you measure a temporal periodicity of the intensity distribution of the radiation. Even in the case of the double slit, behind which the radiation is subject to a spatial redistribution and has a wave-like spatial intensity distribution, no temporal periodicity can be measured.
What is an EM wave
To generate an EM wave, electrons must be accelerated back and forth synchronously. The photons emitted are polarized (electrically parallel to the antenna rod). The number of photons varies between zero (all electrons are at zero acceleration) and a maximum, depending on the power of the wave generator (all electrons have just reached their maximum acceleration). The temporal periodicity of such a wave can be measured, as Hertz did.
TL;DR
In the near-field range of the antenna, the electric and magnetic field components are offset from each other by a quarter of a wavelength.
Spatially, it looks like this:

Since each of the emitted photons makes its contribution to the common EM wave, I assume that the above picture applies exactly to each of the photons.
A photon therefore travels in empty space by progressively changing its electric field into its magnetic field and - by reversing the sign - back into its electric field and so on.
If the photons encounter an obstacle, they “dock” with their field components to the particles of the conductor and move them, i.e. exactly the reverse of the emission process in the transmitting antenna.
BTW, depending on what you want to achieve, you can operate an antenna as an electrical or a magnetic antenna.
One last remark. It is the elegance of nature that the electric subatomic particles have both an electric field and are magnetic dipoles. These particles therefore “pass on” both field components to the photon, which wobbles through space and passes on both components to the absorbing particle. Magic.
TL;DR
